# Oracle UTC Time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timezone

I'm trying to read an Oracle `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` from a database in UTC-5 (NY) as UTC.

Oracle is driving me crazy:

```
SELECT 
from_tz(MAX(TIMESTAMPWITHTIMEZONE),'UTC'),
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(MAX(TIMESTAMPWITHTIMEZONE)),
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(systimestamp), 
SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM TABLE
```

Results:

- `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(systimestamp)` gives me: `2013-02-20 14:59:04`, which is probably right.
- `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` gives me: `2013-02-20 15:59:04` which is my own local Berlin - whatever

#### Now I want to have TIMESTAMPWITHTIMEZONE (TIMESTAMP(6)) as UTC

- `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(MAX(TIMESTAMPWITHTIMEZONE))` is `2013-02-20 08:55:01`
- `from_tz(MAX(TIMESTAMPWITHTIMEZONE),'UTC')` is `2013-02-20 10:55:01`

Srly. Oracle. I want UTC.

Which one is the right one? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Many examples here: http://psoug.org/reference/timestamp.html and here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2243248

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functions are different:

- [`SYS_EXTRACT_UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions186.htm#SQLRF06119) converts a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` to a `TIMESTAMP` (with inferred but absent timezone=UTC).
- [`FROM_TZ`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions068.htm#i999803) converts a `TIMESTAMP` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`

These functions when applied to a single value will in general return a different result:

```
SQL> SELECT sys_extract_utc(localtimestamp) ext,
  2         from_tz(localtimestamp, 'UTC')  from_tz
  3    FROM dual;

EXT                   FROM_TZ
--------------------- ------------------------
2013/02/20 15:34:24   2013/02/20 16:34:24 UTC
```

In the first case the `TIMESTAMP` is **implicitly** given the timezone of the server and then transformed into the equivalent timestamp at the UTC timezone. Note that in general you should stay away from implicit conversions.

In the second case there is no computation between timezones: the `FROM_TZ` function adds the geographical location to a point in time variable.

By the way there is something missing in your example: you can't apply the `FROM_TZ` function on a variable of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` (tested on 9ir2 and 11ir2):

```
SQL> select from_tz(systimestamp, 'UTC') from dual;

select from_tz(systimestamp, 'UTC') from dual

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: 
   expected TIMESTAMP got TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
```

---

Edit following comment:

In your case assuming that your column are of time `TIMESTAMP`, and knowing that they refer to the NY timezone, you could use the [`AT TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699) expression to convert to `UTC`:

```
SQL> SELECT localtimestamp,
  2         from_tz(localtimestamp, 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' utc
  3    FROM dual;

LOCALTIMESTAMP        UTC
--------------------- ------------------------
2013/02/20 17:09:09   2013/02/20 22:09:09 UTC
```

Comment: OK, it is getting more understandable now, I know that DBTimezone is UTC-5 and that Timestamps (now probably without timezone) are inserted in that timezone. - all i should do is collect that timestamp with an additional 5 hours to get UTC? What should i use to get UTC?
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You could use the `AT TIME ZONE` expression to convert a from a time zone to another, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 18c you could use [TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/to_utc_timestamp_tz-function-18c?display_type=printable) function:

> The TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ function converts any valid ISO 8601 date represented as a string into a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE, which can optionally be used as input to the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC function.

```
SELECT TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ(col_name)
FROM tab_name;
```